# SQL Express 2012 - Unable to select "Force Encryption" option in SQL Configuration Manager 11

Tags: sql-server-2012

Sorry if this is a completely stupid question, but I don't know where else to look.

I'm not seeing any options under the "Force Encryption" for my SQL Express 2012 instance.

Here's a screenshot.

[screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqMSz.png)

Might be hard to tell, but the dropdown is empty. It appears as just a thin bar, with no options in it.

I thought maybe it's not allowing me to select "Yes" because there's no SSL certificates imported.

According to my research, there should be an "Import" option on the "Certificate" tab, but I'm not seeing one.

[no option to import certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lc8c9.png)

On a different instance, one that is on version 2008, it will let me select "Yes" to Force Encryption, without the need to install or set up any certificates. Why can't I do the same in 2012?